# mocking the response for the method called inside the same class

Tags: java, spring, junit5

Iam trying to write JUnit test case for the below class scenario.

```
public class Class1{

@Autowired
Class2 class2Obj;

@Autowired
Class3 class3Obj;

public MyResponse searchTheDetails(String id){
GetDetails details;
List<String> names;
id(id!=null){
 details = getDetails(id); //while running JUnit ,**details** value is null always and throwing NPE at next line.
 names = searchByNames(details);
}
return filterName(names);
}

public GetDetails getDetails(String id){
//logic
int i = class3.load().countOccurence(id);//we are using class3 object here
return class2Obj.getData(id,i);//this line was mocked in the below jUnit
}
}
```

JUnit for the above class.

```
@SpringBootTest
class Class1Test{

@InjectMocks
Class1 class1;
@InjectMocks
Class3 class3;
@Mock  
Class2 class2;
MyResponse myResponse;

@BeforeEach
void setUp(){
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
class3 = class3.load();
myResponse = getTheMockResponse();
}

@Test
void test(){
Mockito.doReturn(myResponse).when(class2).getData(Mockito.anyString(),Mocito.anyInt());
MyResponse resp = class1.searchTheDetails("21233");
}
}
```

When the above JUnit test case is executed, it is throwing NullPointerException as the details value returned is null. What is the better approach to solve the above error.TIA.

--EDIT--
In the above code sample, added the class3 dependency logic for better clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case try this code

```
@SpringBootTest
class Class1Test{

@InjectMocks
Class1 class1;
@Mock
Class3 class3;
@Mock  
Class2 class2;
MyResponse myResponse;

@BeforeEach
void setUp(){
this.class1 = new Class1(class1, class3); 
myResponse = getTheMockResponse();
Mockito.when(class2.getData(Mockito.anyString(),Mocito.anyInt())).thenReturn(myResponse);

}

@Test
void test(){
MyResponse resp = class1.searchTheDetails("21233");
}
}
```

Dont forget to change your Class1 class to replace @Autowired injection with constructor injection.

(For the getTheMockResponse() it's a private method in you test class? )

Comment: i cannot remove class3, because we are using it in class1. I will edit my previous post for better clarity.

Comment: please see the original post edited. class3 is required and i have used InjectMocks for class3 in the junit.